# Why can't I get all the images links via response.css?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract all the links to images but I can only extract the main picture on each of the properties page using

```
response.css('div.col-sm-12 img.visible-print-block::attr(src)').get()
```

Apart from that when I try to extract the rest of the images using this code I get an empty array. how to fix this?

```
class WebBox2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    def parse(self, response):
        for prop in response.css('div.grid-item'):
            link = prop.css('div.property-image a::attr(href)').get()
            yield scrapy.Request(
                link,
                callback=self.get_loc,
                meta={'item': {
                    'url': link,
                }},
            )

    def get_loc(self, response):
        item = response.meta.get('item')

        pics_link =  response.css('div.gallery img::attr(src)').getall()

        item['images'] = pics_link

        return item

--------------------------------------------------------------------

class CapeWaterfrontSpider(WebBox2Spider):
    name = "cape_waterfront_estates"
    start_urls = ['https://www.capewaterfrontestates.co.za/template/Properties.vm/listingtype/SALES',
                  'https://www.capewaterfrontestates.co.za/template/Properties.vm/listingtype/MONTHLY_RENTAL']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using `scrapy shell` what the html looks like for scrapy. The content you're trying to get is loaded dynamically, so you'll have to adapt your selector to, for example: `pics_link = response.xpath('//*[@data-nav="thumbs"]//@data-full').extract()`

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped!